Inicios en programación
Me interesa la tecnología, y he decidido enfocarme estas vacaciones en aprender a programar, pero quiero me surge una duda, debería aprender un lenguaje o primero algoritmia ?

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Y todo depende el rumbo que quieras seguir... y algunos te van a decir un lenguaje, y otros algoritmos, pero la verdad deberias aprender algoritmos centrados en un lenguajes para poder encarar las cosas. No vas a poder aprender algoritmos, sin poder aplicarlos a algun lenguaje...

Ambos son esenciales. Usas el lenguaje para implementar algoritmos.
